# Using ODBC in Excel to pull data with a parameter. Is there a way to code in the cell reference instead of manually loading?

Tags: excel, vba, parameters, odbc

I'm pulling in ODBC data to Excel 2015 using the following path:
Excel tab "Data" > "From Other Sources" > "From Microsoft Query" > select my data source > find table and create query

The query is returned with a "?" to elicit the "parameter" option shown below.
[Parameter Pop Up Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgvKm.jpg)

Here is my ODBC code. Is there a way to reference cell "=Sheet1!$E$4" so the pop up doesn't request this information?

```
`With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "ODBC;DSN=####;UID=######;;MODE=SHARE;DBALIAS=####;", 
    Destination:=Range( _
    "$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandText = Array( _
    "SELECT PHPRTT.PHP_PART_NO, PHPRTT.PHPRTT_UPD_TS" & Chr(13) & "" & 
    Chr(10) & "FROM PHPRTT" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE 
    (PHPRTT.PHPRTT_UPD_TS>=?)")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query1"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With`
```

Comment: note: replace `Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10)` with `vbcrlf` for better readability

Comment: Thank you jsotola! That worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is a way. I assume that you refer to the question mark in the code line

```
(PHPRTT.PHPRTT_UPD_TS>=?)")
```

If this is correct then we can replace the "?" with the value or text (if they are different and you need one or another), pluse you need to code it correctly dependng on the data time the "?" stands for, e.g. Number, Text, Date. As an example, assuming it's a text you need and its the Value of the excel cell that you will use as the parameter, you will have this:

```
(PHPRTT.PHPRTT_UPD_TS>=""" & Sheet1!$E$4 & """)")
```

or if it's a number then this:

```
(PHPRTT.PHPRTT_UPD_TS>=" & Sheet1!$E$4 & ")")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Gene, maybe my ODBC driver is of a different type. I receive the following Run Time Error '438'.
"Object doesn't support this property or method."

Comment: I select the cell manually. I think the issue is the implicit limitations of MSFT Query/ODBC that limits my ability to enter in distinct cell references.

My work around is to program in my user/pass to the ODBC query and simply use my macro to refresh the output table in lieu of creating each time.

Answer (score 0):

While this is my own post/question, I have found a work-around that renders my question moot.
My solution is:
 1. create a standalone xlsx with a MSFT Query output table as per normal.
 2. under Data > Connections > Definition > Connection String: make sure your UID and PASS are loaded here
 3. Use your macro to open this file, refresh data, save and then close.

This is not optimal, but will work for now. I'll have multiple files that are in the 10MB file size range instead of the 100kB size, but it'll have to do.